# Open Files, Mime Type, File Extensions Problems

Tags: android, android-studio, text-files, file-extension, file-sharing

i have many problems with my app.
1. I want to make a memo app which open only files with .mem file extension. Everything i tried doesn't work or it worked for all file extensions. What should i use/write in my manifest?

2. When i try to open a file in my app it is only possible when its not direct in the device storage, how can i open it from everywhere?
3. When i try to open a shared .mem file from whatsapp i get no url to the file. What i have to do there?

My current manifest intent filter:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="file" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern="*.*\\.mem" />
            <data android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="*/*" android:pathPattern="*.*\\.mem" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and so i load a file:

```
 if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(appLinkAction)) {
        String appLinkData = intent.getData().getPath();
        File lo = new File(appLinkData);
 }
```

thats the way i share it if its necessary:

```
Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intentShareFile.setType("text/plain");
                        intentShareFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(memo));
                        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Memo teilen über..."));
```

I searched a lot online but nothing helped me. Hope you know what to do.
Thx for every help :D

Comment: `When i try to open a file in my app it is only possible when its not direct in the device storage`???? I think you mean 'when it is in the device storage'. `, how can i open it from everywhere?`. What do you mean with 'from everywhere'? Can you give three examples?

Comment: `When i try to open a shared .mem file from whatsapp i get no url to the file.` ?? I do not see code that tries to get that url.

Comment: What is appLinkAction ? What is the value of appLinkData ?

Comment: AppLinkData should be the path to the storage where the file is located.


It works not when the file is directly in the device storage it has to be in a folder in device storage

Comment: Come to the point. Tell exactly which paths you are talking about. Just answer the questions.

Comment: With that code i cann't load files.

With my modification i can load them but only when they are in a folder

Comment: You did not give the info i asked for.

Comment: The path to the file

Comment: I want to make a new file Extension for my app which you can open in my app from file explorer and from e.g. whatsapp/... 


How to do this all i tried from google didnt work.
Please help me

Comment: You have not given the info i asked for. If you want help you should do that.

Comment: I want a tutorial for that please  applinkaction is the is the action of intent 

Applinkdata should be the path to the file

Comment: Applinkdata should be the url as string but it isnt